# How to get data from other intent? (pass data for intents to other intents)

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm making a actions on google project that will use basic functionality of remembering what the user says and using it for another intent.

So for example, this is what the conversation might look like:

```
1     User: Hello
2     Bot: Hey! What's your name?
3     User: Joel
4     Bot: Your name is Joel, is that correct?
5     User: Yes that is correct
6     Bot: Awesome, it's great to meet you Joel.
```

I know how to get the information initially, but I am having trouble with getting the information (the name 'Joel') passed to another intent that is used purely for confirmation.

Here is what I have:

```
app.intent('greeting', (conv, params) => {
  const context = conv.contexts.set('context');      // working good
  conv.ask(`I got ${params.name}, is that right?`);
});

app.intent('greeting_1', (conv,params) => {
  const context1 = conv.contexts.get('context');  //not working
  conv.ask(`Awesome, it's great to meet yoy ${params.name}`);
 });
```

If this helps, specifically **the error I'm getting reads**:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'userDecision' of undefined
```

How do I get this to work? I have a feeling I have to save the data in userStorage but I've only really had to do that is very basic cases so I'm not to familiar with that.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, hi!

Your initial thought of storing the data in UserStorage might be correct depending on your use case. Let me elaborate:

## Two Ways of Saving Data with Actions On Google Node.JS Client Library

### Storing Data In A Conversation

You can use `conv.data.name = 'Joel'` to save the data between the turns of a conversation. But this data won't be available the next time user comes back.

### Storing Data Permanently (As Long As The User Allows It)

This is where userStorage comes into play. You can use `conv.user.storage.name = 'Joel'` to remember the user's name every time they come back. Keep in mind that this type of permanent storage may require consent from the user depending on where they live.

> **Legal note:** Obtaining consent prior to accessing userStorage. Some
>   countries have regulations that require developers to obtain consent
>   from the user before they can access, or save certain information
>   (e.g. personal information) in the userStorage. If you operate in one
>   of these countries and you want to access, or save such information in
>   userStorage, you must use the Confirmation helper to ask consent to
>   the user and obtain the consent before you can start storing such
>   information in userStorage.

You also need to explain the data you're saving in your Privacy Policy.

**As for you specific use case, storing data that won't change (i.e. name) in userStorage is a much better method. Since if you only save it for one conversation, you'll need to ask for permission again the next time.**

These should cover your basic needs of saving data on the platform. However, if you do need a more complex state management solution, you may want to check [Dialogflow Contexts](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts).

---

**EDIT:** I overlooked that you were already using contexts. But the answer still stands, you don't need to use contexts if all you want to do is to save data during a conversation.

But I think the reason you're having a problem is that you're not setting or getting the context parameters correctly. Take a look at the examples [here](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/dialogflow.contextvalues.html#set) and [here](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/interfaces/dialogflow.context.html#parameters):

The `context.set()` method gets three parameters; name, lifespan and parameters. You're only passing the name of the context in your code.

And, using only `contexts.get()` method isn't enough to read parameters of a context. You need to read them like this:

```
app.intent('Tell Greeting', conv => {
  const context1 = conv.contexts.get('context1')
  const { color, num } = context1.parameters
})
```

---

But, I repeat my original point. You shouldn't make things so complicated for yourself if you don't really need to. Try using `conv.data` and `conv.user.storage` if possible.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer. I have some other intents that would work better for temporary saved data (like a date). Is there a method for saving data then retrieving later?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question.As explained in the answer, if you need to store a data temporarily (only while the conversation is going) use `conv.data`. If you need to save it permanently, use `conv.user.storage`. If you need to save a data for 24 hours and then change it, use `conv.user.storage` but ovewrite it when needed.

Comment: Okay got you there, but since I’m using that data I just got from the user for another intent (so like let’s say I got the name from intent 1, then I have to pass over the information in intent 2) How would I use the data or storage I just got in a (let’s say) conv.ask( ) statement? I’m making a confirmation step so I’ll be needed to use that data in a response like 1 intent later

Comment: Don't think of intents as steps or turns of the conversation. While it might be true in some cases, most of the time your users will be able to jump from one intent to another in a non-linear way, unless you use follow up intents. (which is a good thing) As long as you're using one of the methods I've shown in the answer to save the data, you don't need to pass anything into an intent. You can just set the info in one intent and read it in another intent. Intent 1 =  `conv.data.name = 'Yuksel' ` - Intent 2 = `const name = conv.data.name;` `conv.ask('Hello ' + name);`